# Passing Request Body to Spring Rest Template without using LinkedMultiValueMap

Tags: java, spring, httprequest, resttemplate

I'm using the Spring Rest Template to make an Http PUT request and up until now I have been passing the request body using the following:

```
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
        body.add("account", testAccount);

        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(body, headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity;

        try {
            responseEntity = rest.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity, String.class);
        }
        catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
            log.error("Http PUT failed with response: " + e.getStatusText());
            return ResponseEntity.status(e.getStatusCode()).body(e.getResponseBodyAsString());
        }

        return responseEntity;
```

The request body that gets sent to my target API appears as:

```
{"account":[{"account_id":"495"}]}
```

This works, but my target API is not expecting the `account` object to have an array as a value and is currently giving me a 500 Internal Server Error, so, my question is, how can I get the value of the `'account'` property to be an object rather than an array? For example I would like the request body to appear as:

```
{"account":{"account_id":"495"}}
```

Is there another type of `Map` which can be used which does not accept multiple values?

I would still like to use the `exchange` method if possible.

Any on help on this would be grand! Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was actually simply using a regular `HashMap` instead of the `MultiValueMap`. As seen here the `MultiValueMap`case is used when you want to add an array to a single key in the request body.
Thanks for all the help.